# Regular Expressions (HTML parsing on iPhone)

Tags: iphone, html, xpath, hpple

I am trying to pull data from a website using objective-c.  This is all very new to me, so I've done some research.  What I know now is that I need to use xpath, and I have another wrapper for that called hpple for the iPhone.  I've got it up and running in my project.

I am confused about the way I retrieve information from the site.  Apparently I am to use regular expressions in this line of code:

```
NSArray * a = [doc search:@"//a[@class='sponsor']"];
```

This is just an example.  Is that stuff in the search:@"...." the regular expression?  If so, I guess I can develop the hundreds of patterns that I will need for my program to parse the site (I need a lot of data), but is there a better way?  I'm very lost in this.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is an XPath, not a regular expression. Here's a breakdown:

- All xpaths are interpreted relative to a [context node](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-context-node). In this case, it's the root node.
- `//` is an abbreviation meaning "all descendents"
- `a` means "all child [nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) with a node type of 'a'" (in HTML, that's [anchors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2))
- `[...]` contains a [predicate](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates), refining just which `a` to match

  - `@` is an abbreviation for attribute nodes
  - `@class` means an attribute named "class"
  - `@class='sponsor'` means a class attribute equal to "sponsor". Note this will not match nodes with a class *containing* "sponsor", such as `<a class="big sponsor" ...>`; the class must be *equal*.

All together, we have "'a' nodes descending from the root that have class equal to 'sponsor'".

Comment: Very informative.  By any chance, is there a program that I can use to easily find the proper XPath?  Or is XPath easy enough to work with?

Comment: What do you mean by "proper XPath"? Do you mean find an XPath that will select given nodes? I've seen no app which does that. However, there are plenty of [XPath testers](http://www.google.com/search?q=xpath+test) that let you test whether or not a given XPath selects the nodes you want for a given document. If you use a Mac, try [AquaPath](http://ditchnet.org/aquapath/) to begin with. As for working with XPath, search for tutorials. Some aspects of them are easy to work with; they're a little like evolved file paths (I think it happens at level 30).

Comment: +1 Good answer. A minor: `a` means *children elements named `a`*.

Comment: @Alejandro: d'oh. In my rush to simplify things, I left out anything to do with axes.

Answer (score 0):

That is an XPath expression, not a regular expression. The W3C has an XPath reference here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/.  Basically you are searching for <a> elements with the class "sponsor".

Note that this is a good thing! Regular expressions are bad for parsing HTML.